# GitHub API: How to list in single call both protected and non-protected branches (`/repos/OWNER/REPO/branches` endpoint)

Tags: rest, github

According to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/branches/branches) omitting `protected` parameter should list all the branches from the repository.

> ### protected
>
> Setting to true returns only protected branches. When set to false, only unprotected branches are returned. Omitting this parameter returns all branches.

But with angular repository, it's listing only protected branches (even not sure that all of them)
https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/branches
One nothing is that the default `main` branch is not listed even under the protected flag.
The `tags` endpoint is not listed on API documentation but seems like it returns truncated data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The branches are paged, by default the API returns only the first 30:

> per_page integer
>
> The number of results per page (max 100).
>
> **Default: 30**

> page integer
>
> Page number of the results to fetch.
>
> Default: 1

More [details in how GitHub implements pagination can be found in the docs.](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/traversing-with-pagination)

Comment: Thank you! Can you also point to the tags endpoint documentation? https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/tags?per_page=100

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/tags